# Hide action bar 3 dots but display items

Tags: android, xml, android-toolbar

I am having an issue where i have 2 items in my action bar (one 'refresh' button and one 'Save' Button, but for some reason they do not show, instead they are nested inside an options menu (3 dots). Would anyone know how to remove the 3 dots menu and display my 2 items? I have tried many things but ultimately I just end up removing all three items. Thanks in advance.

Here is my code

add_event_action.xml (this is my menu xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_refresh"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_refresh"
    android:title="Refresh"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_save"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="@string/save"/>
</menu>
```

Here is my Java class

```
public class RandomActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_events_list);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.add_event_action, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            // action with ID action_refresh was selected
            case R.id.action_refresh:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Refresh selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                break;
            // action with ID action_settings was selected
            case R.id.action_save:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Save selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If I understood correctly, you need two menu buttons in your toolbar.

This works for me, place it in your menu.xml:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/done"
    android:title="@string/done"
    app:showAsAction="always|withText"/>
```

Comment: can you accept my answer, it would really help me out. thanks.

Comment: Will do, i can only accept 15min after i posted the question though, so i'll accept it shortly

Answer (score 3):

Try to use `app:showAsAction` instead of `android:showAsAction`

Answer (score 1):

To expand on the other answers somewhat:

When your activity extends from `AppCompatActivity`, your menu items should use `app:showAsAction`. When your activity does not (that is, when you're not using the AppCompat support libraries), your menu items should use `android:showAsAction`.

Documentation: http://tools.android.com/tips/lint-checks

> ### AppCompatResource
>
> Summary: Menu namespace
>
> Priority: 5 / 10
>   Severity: Error
>   Category: Correctness
>
> When using the appcompat library, menu resources should refer to the
>   `showAsAction` in the `app:` namespace, not the `android:` namespace.
>
> Similarly, when not using the appcompat library, you should be using the `android:showAsAction` attribute.